# Select single column data from DataTable to list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable, `dtCpt` which has multiple columns in it. It has a column named `CLAIM_NUMBER`. 
I have a list  `List<long> claimNos;`
I need all the distinct `CLAIM_NUMBER` from datatable `dtCpt` to the list `claimNos`.

I write a code like this

```
claimNos = dtCpt.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new { id = s.Field<long>("CLAIM_NUMBER") }).Distinct().ToList();
```

but it show an error like this

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Is there any easy way to do this in a single line of code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need anonymous type at all. Try that:

```
claimNos = dtCpt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => s.Field<long>("CLAIM_NUMBER"))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Comment: How can I make this line of code generic ?? because I don't want to define dataType. I want the datatype to be picked as per `column.DataType`. Can you help ?